# Update firmware

Tags: samsung, device-firmware, android-10

I have a Samsung Note 9 SM-N960F / DS which I bought in Germany! The first time, the phone was used in an Southeast Europe (SEE) country, so it has an SEE firmware. Service provider shows: SEE/SEE, DBT/DBT on the third line.
So, my question is, can I / should I install DBT firmware?
(What I want to do, is to upgrade Android 9 SEE to Android 10 DBT. Should I do it?)

Thank You

Comment: Are you sure that the country the device was used the first time has an effect on the firmware and it's ability to upgrade? Usually a region lock is applied by the manufacturer before selling it.

Comment: I think so, because when I did put my sim card the first time, there was a message saying wether I wanted to use the phones firmware or the sim card's one. I selected the sim card's, then the phone rebooted, downloaded the firmware and installed it.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/patched-odin-3-13-1-t3762572